# How to use Search Modifier "OR" in Sails.js using Waterline Adapter for Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js, waterline

The below code is written to fetch records containing "sometext" in either "name" or "description". This seems to be not working.

Can someone provide a correct way to implement "OR" searches

Side Note: "AND" function works. "OR" function is not working. sailsjs & sails-mongo version 0.94 is used.

```
Model.find({
     where: {
      or: [
       {name: {contains: req.param('sometext')}},
       {description: {contains: req.param('sometext')}}
      ]
     }, limit: 15, skip: 0, sort: 'name ASC'
    }, callback)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Model.find({
  or: [
    { something: 3 },
    { somethingElse: "foo" }
  ]
}).done(function(err, data) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of applying OR in waterline, sails waterline provides chaining of waterline methods. The find() and where() methods can be chained as follows :

```
User.find({})
.where({
    or: [{
        name: {
            'contains': searchString
        }
    }, {
        description: {
            'contains': searchString
        }
      }
    }]
})
.skip(0)
.limit(15)
.sort({
    name : 1
});
```

In this way, you can chain further more `where` criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/116) with Sails+Waterline 0.9.4. The link goes to an issue opened by the asker. Once it is fixed, it should work using the code specified in the question.